# Freezed program after delete record(GUI)

Tags: java, sql, user-interface

This code:

```
  private void btnDeleteRecordActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    try {
        rs.deleteRow();
        stmt.close();
        rs.close();

        stmt = con.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE,
                ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE);

        String sql = "SELECT * FROM Workers";
        rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);

        rs.next();
        int id_col = rs.getInt("ID");
        String id = Integer.toString(id_col);
        String first = rs.getString("First_Name");
        String last = rs.getString("Last_Name");
        String job = rs.getString("Job_Title");

        textID.setText(id);
        textFirstName.setText(first);
        textLastName.setText(last);
        textJobTitle.setText(job);
    } catch (SQLException err) {
        //  System.out.println(err.getMessage());
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(Workers.this, err.getMessage());
    }

}
```

AfteI delete one row from database the program freeze. I want to that program will be able to work after a delete button te next and prevrious button will be work.

I used thie: http://www.homeandlearn.co.uk/java/delete_a_record_from_a_database.html

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).  Factor out the DB for hard-coded data.

Comment: @ artiny : avoid doing large computing in edt:  See http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/javase/swingworker-137249.html

Comment: that is my error:

Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at Employees.Workers.btnDeleteRecordActionPerformed(Workers.java:801)
 at Employees.Workers.access$600(Workers.java:28)
 at Employees.Workers$7.actionPerformed(Workers.java:268)


workes.java:80
      stmt = con.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE,
                    ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE);

Workers.java:28
public class Workers extends javax.swing.JFrame {


Workers.java:268
  btnDeleteRecordActionPerformed(evt);

Comment: From the "createStatement" it looks like your connection is null.  Also who ever came up with that code should be SHOT (You should never use scope like that).

Answer (score 0):

Firstly:

Rather define you Statement and ResultSet within the method you are doing the work, this is better use of scope and safer especially when working with multi-threaded code...

Secondly:

When querying for "Workers", map each row into a POJO and put all POJO's in a collection, then have your app work with the collection instead of the ResultSet.

Thirdly:

When doing an update/delete, create an update/delete statement and use the entries (you are trying to modify's) id (or some other type of unique reference) to the statement.

Comment: If this is not homework and you have the freedom to use frameworks, I'd recommend using one, they make this sort of thing very simple.  Take a look at frameworks like Hibernate, MyBatis...

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your thread is dying from a NullPointerException. First thing you should do would be to find out where the bug is that is causing the NullPointerException and fix it.